# How to prevent unit test libraries download when a production build is made using c# and dotnet cli?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild, nuget-package

In another languages, when a build for production is performed, there are configurations to avoid libraries or dependencies not related to the build like: unit test, code coverage, etc

[nodes js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268259/how-do-you-prevent-install-of-devdependencies-npm-modules-for-node-js-package)

```
npm install --production
```

[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975818/what-is-scope-under-dependency-in-pom-xml-for)

```
<dependency>...<scope>test</scope>...</dependency>
mvn clean package
```

So my question is:

> How to skip unit test libraries download on production build using c# and dotnet?

### Unsuccessful attempts

- conditional package references

  - [Handling conditional package references in code and unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58547003/handling-conditional-package-references-in-code-and-unit-tests)

### Workaround

To have 02 different *.csproj

- src/Api.csproj with required runtime dependencies
- test/Api.Test.csproj with only unit test dependencies

This is a problem because I cannot set the csproj for testing when I run custom tasks

```
dotnet msbuild  -target:DisplayMessages --project test/Api.Test.csproj
```

Comment: The workaround you mention of having separate test projects is the standard way of doing testing in .NET as outlined in the examples by microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit

Comment: Due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76258850/how-to-create-a-custom-task-only-for-unit-testing-using-dotnet-with-c) I trying have only one csproj :(